# Libreoffice : italics breaking off (messes with replace-function)

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I have been trying to use automatic replace function to place entries starting with italics on their own lines, so for example

lähteä60*F【动】
1. 离开, 出发, 走掉líkāi, chūfā, zǒu diào(poistua). *Vieraat lähtevät*.客人走了kèrén zǒule.*Juna lähtee raiteelta kaksi*. 火车两点离站huǒchē liǎng diǎn lí zhàn.

would turn into 
 1. 离开, 出发, 走掉líkāi, chūfā, zǒu diào(poistua). 
Vieraat lähtevät.客人走了kèrén zǒule.
Juna lähtee raiteelta kaksi. 火车两点离站huǒchē liǎng diǎn lí zhàn.

However, for some reason unknown to me, the replace function (cf. screenshot) breaks up the lines like this:
lähteä60*F【动】
1. 离开, 出发, 走掉líkāi, chūfā, zǒu diào(poistua). 
Vieraat lähtev 
ä 
t.客人走了kèrén zǒule. 
Juna lähtee raiteelta kaksi. 火车两点离站huǒchē liǎng diǎn lí zhàn.
(so the first line "Vieraat lähtevät.客人走了kèrén zǒule." is broken up.)

As far as I can tell, it should be all italics, so I have no idea why it breaks up and no way to examine what's the problem. Trying to save to different formats doesn't seem to help either. There's thousands of pages of this stuff, so the automatic function is really required.

A small sample file of the stuff can be downloaded from here:
http://shakki.info/test.docx.

Some screenshots of the problem:

[image: Original situation]

[image: Replace function]

[image: Unideal result]

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to automate a solution, but I can perhaps explain what's happening. Considering the first chunk of italics, we see it as one chunk, but for some reason it's actually formatted in three chunks as (using html notation for illustration) `<i>Vieraat lähtev</i><i>ä</i><i>t.</i>`. My guess is either the original document was so formatted, or it's an artifact of less-than-perfect importing by LO of a Word doc.

Comment: It's clear that formatting is the issue because of this... If the entire chunk is selected, the formatting is cleared by `Format > Clear Direct Formatting`, and then the chunk is reformatted with the formatting selected from another italic chunk using the Clone Formatting tool, it then becomes `<i>Vieraat lähtevät.</i>` and behaves accordingly in a Find & Replace operation.